# How do I stub a mix-in method in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, mongoid

I'm using the Mongoid class to persist Ruby objects to MongoDB. Example object:

```
class Option
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :created_at, type: Time, default: ->{ Time.now }

end
```

In my tests I find myself stubbing instances after creation to avoid the objects hitting mongo:

```
o1 = Option.new
o1.stub(:save!).and_return true #stub method
o1.name = 'red'
o1.save!
```

The obvious problem is I need to do this for every instance. Is there a way I can stub the `Mongoid::Document.save!` method, i.e. the mix-in instead? That way I can know that any document using the mix-in will have `save!` stubbed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, monkeypatch `Mongoid::Document`, but I would advice against doing so, other tests might need original `save!`. Inconvenience of repeated stubbing can be mitigated by factory method:

```
def option_with_stubbed_save
  option = Option.new
  option.stub(:save!).and_return true
  option
end
```

Comment: Or even better have a method that will stub any object's `save!` method if it has a `save!` method, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/4145069